# В ListView исчезают данные при прокрутке

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

При загрузке страницы загружается ListView со следующим DataTemplate:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRevenueList"
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
          SelectionMode="None"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="15">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Fio}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Department}" FontSize="11" TextColor="Gray"/>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="user.png" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"/>
                            <Label FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="{Binding Reserve}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Label Text="Начислено" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Amount}" FontSize="14" TextColor="Green" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Text="Скидка" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="12" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Discount}" HorizontalOptions="End" FontSize="14" TextColor="Red" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="icon_money.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"/>
                                <Label FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Cash}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                <Image Source="icon_card.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"/>
                                <Label FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Card}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                <Image Source="icon_dms.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"/>
                                <Label FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Dms}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Сразу после загрузки всё нормально отображается. Но при прокрутке вниз данные в почти в каждом Item'е начинают "затираться".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же самое происходит и при возвращении в начало страницы.
После долгих поисков нашел статью про **CachingStrategy**, после чего установил данный параметр в значение **RecycleElement** (позже попробовал и в **RecycleElementAndDataTemplate**), но это не исправило ситуацию.

Какие могут быть варианты решения данной проблемы? На "соседних" страницах, в которых присутствует более простая вёрстка DataTemplate, всё отображается корректно и без каких-либо глюков.

Comment: Была у меня проблема связанная с отрисовкой ViewCell - утечка памяти. Проблему решил с помощью создания пользовательского отрисовщика для ячейки под каждую платформу. Возможно, Вашу проблему это тоже решит: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell

Comment: Уберите вообще CachingStrategy